# Can one use right leg for siddhasana

Tags: scripture, yoga, women, hatha-yoga

[Hatha yoga pradipika](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatha_Yoga_Pradipika) contains posture details of Siddhasana as follows

> Press firmly the **heel of the left foot** against the perineum, and the
> right heel above the male organ. With the chin pressing on the chest,
> one should sit calmly, having restrained the senses, and gaze steadily
> the space between the eyebrows. This is called the Siddha Âsana, the
> opener of the door of salvation.
>
> [[37, Chapter 1, THE HAṬHA YOGA PRADIPIKA]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/hyp/hyp03.htm)

It explicitly makes one point: one has to use the left heel.

Are there any other statements that accept the right heel against the perineum?

Comment: hatha yoga is a form of exercises, it is not an integral part of the hindu religion.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Im wondering about your statement. I agree for first, But second is absolutely wrong.

Comment: @Pandya please look the question now...

Comment: @hanugm Ok. I suggest to make the title more specific.

Comment: Heel presses between rectum and genital. Somewhere in between